# Display both Date and Time in the history pane of GitAhead

Tags: gitahead

I have been using GitAhead as my primary git client for a while. The tool is quite good as I work on both Linux and windows. One bit anoying me is the branch history windows shows only the time for the current day, not for the previous days.

My question: is it configurable to let the pane show both the date AND the time similar to other git GUI clients?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an option for that. Please add a feature request to the issue tracker.